# Block water by filling back in a ramp?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I would like to partially fill back in a moat I dug around my fortress walls and that involuntarily filled with water. Is there a way?

[image]

I have tried the following:

- build a wall connected to a floor at level z+1
- remove the floor.

The wall falls as expected right to level z-1 (the level of the ramp) but it does not fill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructed walls deconstruct when they fall, only a wall made from solidified magma wouldn't. You would need to build a wall in the flooded location. but before you can do that the water needs to be removed. Probably the easiest way is to dig a drain to the edge of the map one Z level below, then dig up into that spot. A screw pump could also remove water long enough to build the wall, but those can be kind of messy.

Comment: @Mark-Ripley Thanks for edits to my poor typing

Comment: In this case there seems to be a convenient river available to pump water into (but that's also where the water is coming from, probably, so it might just make a loop)

Comment: Pumping back into the river would work as well. just build walls around the output so it doesn't flood everywhere

Comment: I just noticed that the "river" might actually be brooke, in which case a channel needs to be dug first